# Formatear LocalTime

Tags: java, localtime

Tengo una duda a la hora de parsear mi Local Time a String para poder importar un archivo csv. El local time en el fichero csv esta con el siguiente formato: "1:20:32" -> (hora, minuto,segundo). Bien, yo he hecho lo siguiente:

```
 LocalTime duracion = LocalTime.parse(tipo, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Y así me salta la excepción porque lógicamente no puede leer el 0 de delante.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como hago para que me acepte la hora sin el 0 de delante?
Ya que en mi fichero todos los campos local time vienen sin 0 delante de la hora cuando solo tiene un digito(0-9) dicha hora.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon un trozo del archivo csv que comentas. También sería conveniente que pusieras código [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que lo podamos probar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta cambiando a "H:mm:ss"

```
LocalTime duracion = LocalTime.parse(tipo, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Tampoco funcionar... gracias de todas formas!!

Comment: @CristianNavarroFernandez, asi si funciona, revisa a fondo que te ocurre.

Comment: Buah vale ya esta es verdad funciona, ha sido por un error tonto. Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda y perdon.

Comment: @CristianNavarroFernandez Me alegra hayas solucionado tu problema. Si mi respuesta a tu pregunta te ha servido puedes marcarla como aceptada. Gracias.